# How to interactively add untracked file in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, interactive

I often use `git add -p` to commit files in pieces in Git, but that doesn't work for untracked files:

```
$ git add -p file
No changes.
```

How can I add this file, but not stage all of it?

I want to add only part of it and commit and leave the rest unstaged.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

1. `git add -N file`

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-add):

> `-N, --intent-to-add`
>       Record only the fact that the path will be added later. An entry for the path is placed in the index with no content. This is useful
>   for, among other things, showing the unstaged content of such files
>   with `git diff` and committing them with `git commit -a`.

This command will add the file empty, so it won't be untracked anymore, but none of it will be staged yet.

```
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   file
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   file
#
```

2. `git add -p file`

Now the file is tracked and `git add -p` works as it should.